# Building an non gradle based project (From Parse.com) into gradle based to use with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, spring, build.gradle

this is my first post, please don't be too harsh.

I want to try out the AnyWall tutorial from [https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android](http://Parse)

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0, I already have downloaded all the possible updates on gradle 2.3, parse 1.9 as such android studio.

I think that this specific tutorial is a non gradle project because it not contain trace from any .gradle relationed file in all the project.

The latest that I have tried is to set up the gradle wrapper by CMD.

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
GRADLE_HOME: C:\Users\Root\Desktop\Spring\gradle-2.3-all\gradle-2.3

I want to show up this tutorial on genymotion, android studio says that my project has 100 errors, most of them are related to parse.

I have also read about Spring framework could help you to set up the gradle system on your project, but this task was a big failure yesterday I tried to set up this by 8 hours, finishing with me at 3am. 
I really appreciate if you could help me with a little rock. ;)

I am attaching the report from android studio.

Information:Using javac 1.8.0_40 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Anywall'
Information:Compilation completed with 100 errors and 1 warning in 18 sec
Information:100 errors
Information:1 warning
Warning:java: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
C:\Users\Root\AndroidStudioProjects\AnyWall-android\google-play-services_lib\Anywall\src\com\parse\anywall\Application.java
    Error:Error:line (6)java: cannot find symbol

```
Error:Error:line (6)java: cannot find symbol
```

symbol:   class Parse
  location: package com.parse
    Error:Error:line (7)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ParseObject
  location: package com.parse
    Error:Error:line (35)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ParseObject
  location: class com.parse.anywall.Application